# How to download files from a webview and open playstore from webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have searched other questions for how to download files from a `WebView`.

I want to be able to download files using website and also allow a user to open the Playstore from the `WebView`. For example, some websites have a link or an ad from their app that opens up the dialogue box to open with Playstore or browser. How do I go about doing that?

Below is the code I have:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Allow third party cookies for Android Lollipop
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView,true);
        }

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        });

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com/");
        mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                //for downloading directly through download manager
                Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download.mp3");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention that it does work but after the file downloads, it says "Cannot open file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What logs related to the "Cannot open file" do you have? please give more info related to this....

As a first approach I recommend to add the missing:

```
    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
```

Comment: The code you gave me work. The "Cannot open file" is after the file has been downloaded and an attempt to open it shows the "Cannot open file" dialogue.